# What is a word for a condition one is born with?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say something like:

> From Freud's perspective, sexual deviances are not [manifest in humans from birth / present in humans from birth].

I need a word that describes a condition that one is born with; specifying that the condition was present from birth.

Comment: Also consider immanent (not to be confused with imminent).

Comment: @JoshuaLamusga: Except of course it would be confused with imminent. ;-)

Comment: predisposition?

Comment: note that simply "natural" is often used here.  For example, in the phrase "natural talent" it (a) literally means what you ask and (b) is the universal phrase for what you ask, in that case.

Comment: Etymologically, "natural" is exactly the right word, but if you were to say "sexual deviances are not natural" it would probably not be understood as intended by anybody.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

**[congenital](http://oxfordindex.oup.com/search?q=congenital)**

> (especially of a disease or physical abnormality) present from birth.
>   (of a person) having a particular trait from birth or by firmly established habit.

and

> adj. ... describing a condition that is recognized at birth or that is believed to have been present since birth. Congenital malformations include all disorders present at birth whether they are inherited or caused by an environmental factor....
>   <sub>[Oxford Concise Medical Dictionary](http://www.oxfordreference.com/search?q=congenital&searchBtn=Search&isQuickSearch=true) (9 ed.)</sub>

Comment: Can the word "congenital" really be used to describe something psychological, such as "sexual deviances", as per the original question? I've only heard it used for physical malformations/disorders

Comment: @Jake the OP wants to say : "From Freud's perspective,  sexual deviances are *not* ______.

Comment: Right - but by opinion, not by definition. In other words, another psychologist might disagree with Freud, and say that sexual deviances are indeed [manifest from birth] - and I don't think they'd describe that as being congenital

Comment: I limit myself to suggesting the most appropriate word, in my opinion. :)

Comment: @Jake: "Congenital liar" is a pretty common phrase.

Comment: @NateEldredge and Mari-Lou A (StackExchange only lets me @ reply one person) - That's very true! I wasn't trying to be nit-picky, just honestly wondering if that was a potential use of that word. I quite like the phrase "congenital liar"!

Comment: Congenital is the proper term. I had my right eye poked out by birthing tongs out during the birthing process. My medical records show the injury as "congenital." Whatever you pop out with, regardless of the reason, is congenital.  [The word literally means:](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=congenital&allowed_in_frame=0) 
"existing from birth," 1796, from Latin congenitus, from com- "together, with" (see com-) + genitus, past participle of gignere "to beget"

Comment: I would expect people to think f something congenital as something you get through your genes, or form your parents. Not saying it is wrong, but could be misconstrued in this context, I think.

Comment: I was the 100th upvoter :) ! Congratulations!

Comment: The first .........

Comment: **deviation** from Late Latin *deviatus*, past participle of deviare "turn aside, turn out of the way". From 1630s as "departure from a certain standard or rule of conduct or original plan." --which implies that one was one way, and turned another. The etymological origin indicates a change, which I guess wouldn't necessarily need to be post-birth...

Answer (score 77):

Consider **innate** (existing in one from birth; inborn; native)

> Example: We do not know whether musical ability is innate or
>   acquired.

*Edit: I just realized that this word appears in @Josh61 "Inborn" definition.*

Comment: On reading the question title, my first reaction was "congenital", but on reading the context in the question itself, "innate" is a better choice, IMO. A child may be born with a _congenital_ heart defect, but humans have an _innate_ ability to recognize faces. That is, face recognition is part of being human - everyone has it - but "congenital" is an individual condition.

Answer (score 30):

***[Inborn](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inborn):***

> - existing from birth; congenital; innate
> - Existing naturally or by heredity rather than being learned through experience:
>
>   - *"Flight is an inborn skill; young birds don't have to learn how" (Marie Read).*

(The Free Dictionary)

Answer (score 24):

Congenital is my first choice, but if you want something more on the meta-physical level, consider [inherent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inherent):

> belonging to the basic nature of someone or something
>
> (Merriam-Webster)

Comment: +1 This would be my choice in the OP's context. Congenital is usually used for physical attributes.

Comment: Agreed. Also, sexual deviance is not a condition.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you should go for :

innate: An innate quality or ability is one that you were born with, not one you have learned:

or

inherent :existing in something as a permanent, essential, or characteristic attribute.

or

intrinsic : Of or relating to the essential nature of a thing. Situated within or belonging solely to the organ or body part on which it acts.

or

inborn : natural

P.S. : Definitions from Google Dictionary

Comment: Don't know why these have been downvoted, they are good words.

Comment: @IainHolder Maybe the downvotes were cast because *innate* has already been suggested by [Graffito](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/321870/44619), *inherent* by [Michael J](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/321979/44619) and there's no explanation or reference for *intrinsic*, which is the worst suggestion of the lot.

Comment: I concur. This answer is of Very Low Quality, and does risk deletion unless it's enhanced with published definitions which justify these suggestions.

Comment: @abcd Please [format and reference quotes correctly](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 4):

**Congenital** is indeed oft used, however it means that it is a lineage trait as well (literally from *con genites* (Latin) meaning *with father*): so whilst popular in use, not strictly correct unless unless referring to a condition suffered by progenitors as well.

From the point of view of non-physical traits: perhaps **inherent**, or **intrinsic** might serve better when dealing with psychological conditions allowing a choice for the intent you wish to construe as to the capability of the individual to resist their predestined traits: if inherent, then they may well be able to resist, if intrinsic, then the trait is so fundamental as to be an integral part and unavoidable in the long run.  **Innate** can work too, as it stems from the Latin for in/since birth.

For example:

> From Freud's perspective, sexual deviances are not **inherent**

i.e. not part of the basic nature of the subject

> From Freud's perspective, sexual deviances are not **intrinsic**

i.e. not part of the integral nature of the subject

> From Freud's perspective, sexual deviances are not **innate**

i.e. not part of the birth-state of the subject

Something just occurred to me as well, the trait, described as psychological may well have a physiological cause (brain lesions, altered brain formation) and hence be able to be classified as a more properly physical trait, which could allow you to rename the trait as such.

Answer (score 2):

**Genetic**

That's what most American English speakers would say in that case. It isn't technically correct, but we use the word for things that aren't caused by genes.

"Insanity is *genetic*, you get it from your children"

"She has a *genetic* heart condition"

"Many Americans believe that homosexuality is *genetic*"

Comment: I don't think that's a usage issue, but rather a scientific literacy issue. I think when people say this they genuinely mean *genetic* and are simply misunderstanding the science, as opposed to meaning something other than the scientific definition. (Of course, the first example you gave is a common joke, and the use of *genetic* there is tongue-in-cheek.)

Comment: Sure, I agree with that. I'm positively amazed that this isn't getting massive upvotes, because anyone who speaks American will have heard this, almost every time, when we need to say a sentence like the example. This is absolutely the most common way an American speaker would say it. Maybe in UK it's different, I don't know.

Comment: Genetic though isn't what I'm looking for in this context. Genetic would imply the 'sexual deviance' is a *precondition*, determined *prior* to birth. I am simply looking for a word that describes something as if it was assigned *at* birth.

Comment: Americans use the word both ways. Sorry if I wasn't clear on that.

Comment: @Jasmine ha that's a pretty funny joke, the first one.

Answer (score 1):

***hereditary***

> : passing, or capable of passing, naturally from parent to offspring through the genes
>
> [RHKWCD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hereditary)
>
> *Hemophilia is a hereditary condition.*

***atavistic***

> : reappearing after being absent from a strain of organism for several generations. Used of an inherited trait.
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Student Science](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/atavistic)

Comment: Neither of these words fit the OP's context.

Comment: This implies the trait is shared by one's parents/ancestors.  A birth defect, for example, may not be hereditary, but it's still present from birth.

Answer (score 1):

'innate' works, right? ..but I like to use 'instinctive'.

It provides a 'tip of the hat' towards the world of life before us and their wisdom of workable interconnection to resources which constructively evolves.

From Wikipedia...
INSTINCTIVE
...relating to or prompted by instinct; apparently unconscious or automatic.
"an instinctive distaste for conflict"
(of a person) doing or being a specified thing apparently naturally or automatically.
"an instinctive writer"
[image]!

Answer (score 0):

"**Proband**" is the term geneticists use to define someone who has a genetic condition they wish to track in a family tree.   A person confirmed with the condition is an "affected proband"  a person unconfirmed is a "suspected proband"

Comment: Can you add a reference to back your claim? :)

Answer (score -6):

It's not perfect for this usage, but **inveterate** is a good word to have in your tool belt:

> 1.
>   settled or confirmed in a habit, practice, feeling, or the like:
>   *an inveterate gambler*.
>
> 2.
>   firmly established by long continuance, as a disease, habit, practice, feeling, etc.; chronic.

[via [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inveterate)]